# Extract JSON response from any website using the network tab in chrome developer tools

Tags: python, json, selenium, xmlhttprequest, selenium-chromedriver

I was wondering if there is any way that we can extract the JSON Response from any website that produces the data dynamically and automate this using python. What I am looking for is, monitor the network tab only for a particular file. When I scroll through the site and once the file I am looking for pops up in the network tab, I need to extract that specific file. I want to achieve this without any software. I was searching tutorials for this all over youtube and couldn't find.

Comment: You want to use an API library and hit the api url directly, skip the browswer interaction if possible. Can you share the URL and more details about what you want to extract?  - This is a good resource for an intro to API testing with python https://medium.com/@peter.jp.xie/rest-api-testing-using-python-751022c364b8